# How to use a SQL dynamic query to create a template with dynamic columns in Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have a SQL query which generates fix number of columns and a dynamic columns logic, e.g.
ID, Name, DOB, Address, Dynamic1, Dynamic2...... DynamicN

The number of dynamic columns are unknown and no maximum value is defined. The list of dynamic column names are stored in a database table.

I have no problem to build the query and show the result in SQL management studio.

But I could not figure out how to create a report template in Report Builder. Anyone has some good example to archive this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post your query?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using temp table

1. Create a Temp table outside the dynamic query
2. Alter its columns inside the dynamic query by adding your dynamic columns
3. Then add your result set to it inside dynamic query
4. Write select statement of that temp table outside the dynamic query
5. Then drop it :)